# Connecting Java se Client to Glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

We are having some difficulties connecting our Java SE standalone client with the EJB module deployed on a remote GlassFish server.

Pointers to how we are supposed to connect our client would be appreciated.

The client code we currently has to get the initial context:

```
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "*remotehost*");
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "portNumber");
```

javax.naming.InitialContext ic = new javax.naming.InitialContext(props);

*We have tried several different port numbers; 3700, 7676, 8080..

The closest we are getting, got us the error: "Error in GIOP magic".

I read that jms are using port 7676 as a broker port for a bunch of dynamically generated ports, but can't figure out how to specify those ports in order to create proper port-forwards.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some material [here](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html), which does indicate that the default port is 3700.

This [reference](http://www.coderanch.com/t/93130/Other-Java-Products-Servers/accessing-Initial-context-glassfish) also indicates that some particualr jars may be needed.

Answer (score 0):

The default port for Glassfish is 3700.  I wrote an article [here](http://jandrewthompson.blogspot.com/2009/12/access-remote-ejb-from-stand-alone.html) that gives explicit instruction on how to do this.  Hope this helps. Also, make sure you're also using the correct verions of appserv-rt.jar along with all of its dependencies in your client project.

-- andrew